# How can I combine rows and add a column in SQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table which shows the number of 200 and 404 responses from a website for each day. I need to rearrange it so each date is displayed once per row, and the status codes become the columns.

```
    status     |           date         |  num  
---------------+------------------------+-------
 200 OK        | 2016-07-31 00:00:00+00 | 45516
 404 NOT FOUND | 2016-07-31 00:00:00+00 |   329
 200 OK        | 2016-07-30 00:00:00+00 | 54676
 404 NOT FOUND | 2016-07-30 00:00:00+00 |   397
 200 OK        | 2016-07-29 00:00:00+00 | 54569
 404 NOT FOUND | 2016-07-29 00:00:00+00 |   382
 200 OK        | 2016-07-28 00:00:00+00 | 54404
 404 NOT FOUND | 2016-07-28 00:00:00+00 |   393
```

What I'm ultimately trying to find out is the percentage of responses which are 404 on each day. Something like `select (date.200 / date.404) from mytable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    "date"::date,
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN status LIKE '404%' THEN num ELSE 0 END) / SUM(num) AS percentage
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "date"::date
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: each day, so you may want to group by the date as well.

Comment: @ian-campbell The query works fine in the demo.  Are you sure that you have the right table name etc.?

Comment: None of the percentages should be anywhere close to 50% though.

Comment: @ian-campbell They are all 50% using the 8 rows of sample data you provided.

Comment: The percentage of 404 codes on July 31 is 0.72%.  Dividing 329 by 45516

Comment: @ian-campbell Sorry for the mistake.  It looks like you want to weight an HTTP response on a given day by the `num` column.  My updated query does this.

Comment: I wish it would work for me. I keep getting this error `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "100.0"` The above table is the result of a previous SELECT statement by the way, so I'm calling your select statement on that one.

Comment: @ian-campbell Sorry, there was a missing comma.  Reload the page.  FYI you should be able to figure this out yourself ideally.

Comment: Yes ideally I could figure everything out myself. Wouldn't that be grand.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is called "Pivot Table" and usually it's achieved in Postgres by using "tablefunc" extension https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html.

But in this simple scenario I'd choose plain SQL approach with "manual pivoting" (like described  here http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/07/simple-case-for-pivoting-in-sql/):

```
select
  date,
  sum(case when left(status, 3) = '200' then num end) as status200,
  sum(case when left(status, 3) = '404' then num end) as status404
from
  log
group by 1
order by 1 desc;
```

Notice, that sum() allows you to have multiple records with the same day and same status -- but with your table structure this will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join

```
 select a.date, a.num num_200, b.num num_404, a.num num_200/b.num num_404 rate
 from my_table a
 left join my_table b on a.date = b.date  and b.status= '404 NOT FOUND'
 where a.status= '200 OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
;WITH PivotData
AS (
    SELECT [Date], -- grouping element
        [Status], -- spreading element
        Number -- aggregating element
    FROM StatusEntries
    )
SELECT [Date]
    ,[200 OK]
    ,[404 NOT FOUND]
FROM PivotData
Pivot(Sum(Number) FOR [Status] IN (
            [200 OK]
            ,[404 NOT FOUND]
            )) AS P;
```